# using where clause and date range in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble pulling a query where i want to return results that contain a particular word in a field AND that are between a certain date range.  The query i am using now is:

```
        $month_no = date('m');
        $month_day = date('d');         
        $query="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ((user_purchased LIKE '%john%') AND (request_date BETWEEN '2011-$month_no-$month_day' AND '2011-$month_no-$month_day')) ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);  echo $num_rows;
```

My date format in the 'request_date field is like this:
2011-10-03 12:30:34

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try:

```
BETWEEN '2011-$month_no-$month_day 00:00:00' AND
'2011-$month_no-$month_day 23:59:59')) ";
```

Comment: + 1 This is correct (if the user is trying to get records for that day and also wants to use the same query for ranges) but try to phrase your answers as answers, not questions. Questions can be placed in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

Given your BETWEEN date ranges are the same, why not try

```
... WHERE (DATE(requested_date) = "2011-$month_no-$month_day")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, as I only know how to do it with an Oracle DB - there you would use the *to_date* function as in

```
  ... WHERE date = TO_DATE('20110820','YYYYMMDD') ...
```

or

```
  ... WHERE (date => TO_DATE('20110801','YYYYMMDD')) AND (date <= TO_DATE('20110831','YYYYMMDD'))
```

Maybe it's worth checking if mysql needs such a function call also.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $m = date('m');
  $d = date('d');
  $qry = " SELECT * FROM `table`
  WHERE ( requested_date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2011-$m-$d', ''%Y-%m-%d'') 
                       AND DATE_FORMAT('2011-$m-$d', ''%Y-%m-%d'') )
  AND user_purchased LIKE '%john%' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether `request_date` (which I suppose is datetime) has date part `'2011-$month_no-$month_day'`, try this:

```
    $query="SELECT * FROM `table` 
            WHERE (user_purchased LIKE '%john%') 
              AND (request_date >= '2011-$month_no-$month_day')
              AND (request_date <  '2011-$month_no-$month_day' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
            ";
```